# How to hide panel and its content on mouse event

Tags: c#, winforms

In my form, I have a `panel` with picture boxes on it.  When the mouse hovers over the `panel` the picture boxes should show.  When the mouse leaves, the picture boxes should hide.

At first I tried

```
panel1.visible = true;
```

and

```
panel1.visible = false;
```

I thought this would do, but it doesn't work.  Then I tried the following method

```
namespace Drawing_Program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        PictureBox[] Boxes = new PictureBox[12];

        public Form1()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var pb in Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
            {
                Boxes[i] = pb;                
                i++;
            }           

        }

        private void panel1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Boxes.Length; i++) {
                this.Boxes[i].Visible = true;  // error gives here
            }



        }

        private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Boxes.Length; i++)
            {
                this.Boxes[i].Visible = false;
            }


        }
```

but I am getting the following error:

> nullreferenceException was unhandled: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Please tell me what is wrong or how to do this properly.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Form` is not the direct parent of the `PictureBox` controls. So I'm betting your `Boxes` array is `{ null, null, null,... }`. If `panel1` is the direct parent of all of the `PictureBox` controls, you should be able to populate your `Boxes` array as follows:

```
Boxes = panel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 this also resolves the problem with the constant number in the array initializer `= new PictureBox[12]` which lead to the error IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of `Boxes[i]` is null. Use the debugger to check this, and see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net).

My guess is that you have less than 12 picture boxes and not all of your array elements are references to one of those, but rather remain uninitialized (null).

Your `foreach`-loop will only run as often as you have pictureboxes. If you only have 11 (or less), `Boxes[11]` will be null.

When changing the visibility and i reaches 11, with `Boxes[i].Visible` you are dereferencing `null` which probably causes your exception.

Answer (score 0):

try this
place your controls in a panel say(panel2) and sets it visibility to false .
place this panel in another panel say(panel1) and 
on the mouse events of panel1 try this code

```
   private void panel1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Visible = true;
        }

   private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            panel2.Visible = false;
       }
```

i tried this it is working.

Comment: it works but for my case panel1 and panel2 should be same height and width and it don't work since one panel is covered by another one

Comment: @user1478137: Then you now have a layout issue that you need to resolve by repositioning the panels.